# How to use go mod with local package and docker?

Tags: docker, go, dependencies, dependency-management, go-modules

I have two go modules `github.com/myuser/mymainrepo` and `github.com/myuser/commonrepo`

Here is how i have the files in my local computer

```
- allmyrepos  
 - mymainrepo
   - Dockerfile
   - go.mod
 - commonrepo
   - go.mod
```

#### mymainrepo/go.mod

```
...
require (
  github.com/myuser/commonrepo
)

replace (
  github.com/myuser/commonrepo => ../commonrepo
)
```

It works well i can do local development with it. Problem happens when i'm building docker image of mymainrepo

#### mymainrepo/Dockerfile

```
...
WORKDIR /go/src/mymainrepo

COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download


COPY ./ ./
RUN go build -o appbinary
...
```

Here `replace` replaces `github.com/myuser/commonrepo` with `../commonrepo` but in Docker  `/go/src/commonrepo` does not exists.

I'm building the Docker image on CI/CD which needs to fetch directly from remote github url but i also need to do local development on `commonrepo`. How can i do both ?

I tried to put all my files in `GOPATH` so it's `~/go/src/github.com/myuser/commonrepo` and `go/src/github.com/myuser/mymainrepo`. And i removed the `replace` directive. But it looks for `commonrepo` inside `~/go/pkg/mod/...` that's downloaded from github.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? I have the exact same problem. Can you please share your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create two `go.mod` files: one for local development, and one for your build. You can name it `go.build.mod` for example.

Keep the `replace` directive in your `go.mod` file but remove it from `go.build.mod`.

Finally, in your `Dockerfile`:

```
COPY go.build.mod ./go.mod
COPY go.sum ./
```

Comment: ok. But what if I want to keep the 'replace' for the build also, is there a way without creating 2 go.mod files?

Comment: @ArjunAjith not as far as I know. But if the replace are the same for both, simply use one .mod file and copy the required resources during your image build steps.

Comment: I'd say your solution won't work for this specific question. Probably the OP wants to have the local changes of "../commonrepo" within the container, and not the version specified in the other go.mod, which likely will point to a valid go module, but with a totally different changes

Comment: after that when someone doing `go get ...` how do you make sure the package also going to `go.build.mod` file?
they will need to remember every time to add it manual?

Answer (score 4):

I still can't find other better solution even the voted answer doesn't work for me. Here a trick I've done that workaround for me. This is an example structure for doing this:

```
|---sample
|   |---...
|   |---go.mod
|   |---Dockerfile
|---core
|   |---...
|   |---go.mod
```

1. We know that docker build error when it can't find our local module. Let's make one in the builder process:

```
# Use the offical golang image to create a binary.
# This is based on Debian and sets the GOPATH to /go.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/golang
FROM golang:1.16.3-buster AS builder

# Copy core library
RUN mkdir /core
COPY core/ /core

# Create and change to the app directory.
WORKDIR /app

# Retrieve application dependencies.
# This allows the container build to reuse cached dependencies.
# Expecting to copy go.mod and if present go.sum.
COPY go.* ./
RUN go mod download

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . ./

# Build the binary
RUN go build -o /app/sample cmd/main.go
...
...
```

Ok, our working dir is `/app` and our core lib placed next to it `/core`.

2. Let's make a trick when build a docker image! Yeah, you know it.

```
cp -R ../core . && docker build --tag sample-service . && rm -R core/
```

***Update***
A way better, create a `Makefile` next to `Dockerfile`, with content below:

```
build:
    cp -R ../core .
    docker build -t sample-service .
    rm -R core/
```

Then command, `make build` in the `sample` directory.

You can create `make submit` or `make deploy` commands as you like to.

=> Production ready!

Be aware that if there's an error occurs during docker build process, it won't delete back the `core` folder we have copied to `sample`.

Pls let me know if you find any better solution. ;)